# Find user has both the permission in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

A user table has id and user_name and a second table which has user-related permission user_id and perm_id

User Table

| id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ashok |
| 2 | Anil |
| 3 | Sunil |
| 4 | kanan |

Permission Table

| user_id | perm_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |

Now the problem that needs to find is

1. User must have perm_id=7 and must not have perm_id=10 however, can have other perm_ids like 1,2,3,11, etc in the permission table is type "USER_TYPE_A".
2. User must have both the perm_id in (7,10) in the permission table is type "USER_TYPE_B".
3. User must not fall under 1 and 2 criteria which means Must not have both the perm_id in (7,10) is type "USER_TYPE_C".

Now, have to write the query which will show user_name along with User_type.

What will be the best way to get a result please suggest.
Thanks:)

Comment: Can you please post your attempts? Also what is the user type? There's no such column in your sample data

Comment: If you show us the ways we'll tell you which is best

Comment: I think you mixed column headers. There is no perm_id 7 or 10...

Comment: yeah! sure I tried with a case statement 

select user_name case when perm_id in (7,10) then 'USER_TYPE_B'
when perm_id not in (7,10) then 'USER_TYPE_C' and perm_id not in (10) then 'USER_TYPE_A' from user u, perm p where u.id = p.user_id;

this returns multiple records for the single user it should be one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could express this using `case` and `exists`:

```
select u.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from permissions p
                          where p.user_id = u.id and p.perm_id = 7
                         )
             then (case when exists (select 1
                                     from permissions p
                                     where p.user_id = u.id and p.perm_id = 10
                                    )
                        then 'USER_TYPE_B'
                        else 'USER_TYPE_A'
                   end)
             else 'USER_TYPE_C'
        end) as type 
from users u;
```

Although this is a bit cumbersome, it skips outer aggregations which should benefit performance -- particularly with an index on `permissions(user_id, perm_id)`.

Actually, you can also express this using `left join`, assuming you don't have duplicate permissions for the same user:

```
select u.*,
       (case when p7.user_id is not null and p10.user_id is null
             then 'USER_TYPE_A'
             when p7.user_id is not null and p10.user_id is not null
             then 'USER_TYPE_B'
             else 'USER_TYPE_C'
        end) as type
from users u left join
     permmissions p7
     on p7.user_id = u.id and p7.perm_id = 7 left join
     permissions p10
     on p10.user_id = u.id and p10.perm_id = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understad well, you need to check the permissions' types for each user and then implement some logic based on the result; if so, this could be a way:

```
select user_name,
        case
            when perm_id_7 > 0 and perm_id_10 = 0 then 'USER_TYPE_A'
            when perm_id_7 > 0 and perm_id_10 > 0 then 'USER_TYPE_B'
            when perm_id_7 = 0 and perm_id_10 = 0 then 'USER_TYPE_C' /* do you need this condition or simply an ELSE ? */
        end as user_type
from 
(        
    select user_name,
            count ( case when perm_id =  7 then 1 end) as perm_id_7,
            count ( case when perm_id = 10 then 1 end) as perm_id_10
    from User_Table U
        left outer join Permission_Table p
            on u.id = p.user_id
    group by user_name  
)
```

This is based for clarity on an inner query which counts the permission types per user and an external one that determines the user type.

With your data, this gives:

```
user_name   user_type
Ashok       USER_TYPE_B
Sunil       USER_TYPE_A
kanan       USER_TYPE_C
Anil        USER_TYPE_B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select USER_TYPE_A, user_id, name
from user
where user_id in  (select user_id from Permission where perm_id = 7)
and user_id not in  (select user_id from Permission where perm_id = 10)
union
select USER_TYPE_B, user_id, name
from user
where user_id not in  (select user_id from Permission where perm_id = 7)
and user_id not in  (select user_id from Permission where perm_id = 10)
union
select USER_TYPE_C, user_id, name
from user
where user_id in  (select user_id from Permission where perm_id = 7)
and user_id in  (select user_id from Permission where perm_id = 10)
```

This is an easy-to-debug approach - you can tweak each select statement and union them all together once you're happy. @aleksej's is more elegant, though!